# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid column name 'PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess'.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that there is no such column `PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess` inside your database table.

Maybe you have got a spelling mistake there.

Comment: This is my first University project and I have searched using VisualStudio for anything containing "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess" and this has been unsuccessful. Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you searched the whole solution? The error indicates that you have an SQL statement containing "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess" somewhere in there.

Comment: Yes, i have used the search entire solution shortcut and this has still not found any code containing "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess"

Comment: Than this will be the issue. Please look for your SQL statements and include the column "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess" to fetch in your respective SELECT statement.